# How to get rid of tthe following error --Failed to save Chrome preferences: FileSystemException: Cannot open file ,path='C:\Users\HP\AppDate/Local?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

When I run my application with the command flutter run -d chrome,my app is establishing connection with chrome,but the browser is blank and i cant see any content in browser,in the console it throws the following error
Failed to save Chrome preferences: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.78af2e68\flutter_tools_chrome_device.ff7bb79d\Default\Cache\data_0' (OS Error: The process cannot
access the file because it is being used by another process.
, errno = 32)